# What could be the reason for this error message?

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl, ogre, jmonkeyengine

It used to work but now I don't know what is the matter. I'm trying to start the project but it can't find a file that is seemingly provided. What could be the specific issue?

[image]

I've checked that the file really is there and that the folder is on the Java build path. What more needs to be done? I use eclipse juno and this error is part of a larger project that I'm doing, it's a small game that uses the jme3 engine and it did work to package it, now I've power cycled my laptop and reinstalling everything then I can't seem to get back to where I were. Any ideas?

Comment: Too vague. At least tell us what software you are using.

Comment: @Mika I've updated with more info. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check permissions for that file or the folder it is in. Whenever an app cannot find a file that is actually there, it usually has something to do with permissions.